# Is there a way to pin a Firefox URL as a separate item on the Windows 10 taskbar?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, taskbar, shortcuts

A client wants a link to his Gmail pinned to his Windows 10 taskbar. He does not want it to be a `Pinned` item on the Jump List for Firefox.  Instead, he wants a separate pinned item all on its own for the link. I know that I can use a switch/argument appended to a desktop shortcut for Firefox, but I don't think I can pin a shortcut to the taskbar, at least not without installing something like DisplayFusion (which is my last resort). Could I maybe pin a scheduled task somehow?

This particular client is very particular about things, but he is very wealthy and provides me with a lot of work, so I try and do everything he wants as exactly to his specifications as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the entire process isn't quite as simple as it is with Chrome or Edge, it is still relatively easy:

> 1. Create a new Desktop shortcut that points to Firefox. The easiest method is to open the Firefox installation directory, right-click on
>      firefox.exe, and select **Create shortcut** from the context menu. The
>      default 64-bit Firefox installation directory is **C:\Program
>      Files\Mozilla Firefox**, while the default 32-bit Firefox installation
>      directory is **C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox**.
> 2. Select **Yes** when Windows informs you that the shortcut cannot be created in the Firefox directory. The shortcut is created on the
>      desktop, instead.
>
>    [image: Shortcut Warning]
> 3. Right-click on the new Firefox shortcut and select **Properties** from the menu.
> 4. Append the URL of the site that you want opened by the shortcut within the **Target** field, e.g., **"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
>      -url https://superuser.com/**
>
>    [image: Firefox Shortcut Properties]
> 5. Click on **OK** to save the changes.
> 6. Right-click on the desktop shortcut and select **Rename** to change it to something more appropriate.  In our example, we decided on "Super User"
> 7. Right-click on the desktop shortcut again and select **Pin to taskbar**. Optionally, you may delete the desktop shortcut once you are done.
>
>    [image: Pin to taskbar]
>      [image: Firefox Taskbar Shortcut]

Sources:
[Add your favorite websites to the Windows 10 Taskbar](https://www.ghacks.net/2017/08/25/add-your-favorite-websites-to-the-windows-10-taskbar/)
[How do I pin a Firefox shortcut to the taskbar in Windows 10?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1170305)

Comment: This worked like a charm! I am now using the same method for increased productivity (fewer clicks to get somewhere) myself. Thank you!

Comment: I had no idea that a shortcut to a program with a swich/argument at the end could be pinned pinned as a separate item as a normal shortcut to the same program. Again, thanks!

Comment: Always glad to help! And yes, for those people who are big fans of managing their Windows operating system via the taskbar, customized shortcuts are very useful.

Comment: this works but it will not be opened in a separate window, like a separate app. Any way to achieve this? It's possible in Chrome

Comment: @tinker  yes, you can do that. When you append the URL within the shortcut's Target field, instead of using **-url** before the hyperlink address, change the syntax to **-new-window**

Comment: And the list of all the arguments: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/CommandLineOptions#Windows